# Where should I install older framework version from if I already have other versions installed?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Is it possible to install the .NET Framework 1.1 on Windows Vista, if so, how/where from?

I already have .NET Framework 2.0, 3.0, 3.5 and Visual Studio 2008 installed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Just grab the download and install it.

You can get it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=262d25e3-f589-4842-8157-034d1e7cf3a3&displaylang=en).

If you want do *develop* using .NET 1.1, you will need the SDK from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=9B3A2CA6-3647-4070-9F41-A333C6B9181D&displaylang=en).